# How to Save Android Crash Logs

Tags: android

Save the Application Crash report to file.

I do not want to Read the entire ADB log messages, but only the Crash Log Messages.

Regards,
Vinay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Crashlytics` it is used to track your crash reports.
[Register here](http://try.crashlytics.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I have used ACRA and it's very good. You can get it [here](http://www.acra.ch/). It's free, and open source.